# How to handle user pasting a text with bold,italic styling and table in a django text area?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to design a webpage where users can copy paste their word document contents ,but when I try to copy paste to my django textarea, The effect of bold,italic etc. are missing and table structure is also missing

None of the fields available in django model seems to work

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class UserForm(models.Model):
    Body_content=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Expecting to copy paste directly from word document to text area without losing basic styling and table.

Answer (score 1):

I used django-ckeditor which serves the purpose